# Play 2.0. Ebean. OneToMany orphan removal broken

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

I need some help.
I have two classes with onetomany relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Parent extends Model{

  @Id
  public Long id;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FeatchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  public List<Child> children;

}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Child extends Model{

  @Id
  public Long id;

}
```

So when i call remove() Child entity do not remove from DB.

```
Parent parent = Parent.find.byId(id);
parent.children.remove(parent.children.get(0));
parent.save();
```

And next time I find.byId - all children is there, like they never been deleted :(

Play 2.0.4, inMemory database.

Please make me know if any other informaition is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some more tinkering with this and realized why this doesn't work.

Since you have a unidirectional relationship without any join table, to actually delete the association would mean to delete the corresponding child record (or at least update the parent_id column). It is probably a good thing that EBean doesn't do this, because it doesn't know/checks if perhaps some other table has a foreign key relationship to Child.

What you can do is to explicitly indicate that no other table has a FK relationship to child, that it is "owned" by Parent and it is OK that Ebean removes the entity altogether when removed from the relationship. This is done by adding a `@PrivateOwned` annotation on the `children` attribute of `Parent`.

This post tipped me of: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ebean/dXPWpJCQkj8

Comment: updated answer is really a new answer.. anyway, please try it!